# shell script to print sum of digits of the given num.In case of negative num is given as input, display Not a positive num as o/p

Tags: unix

I'm getting the proper output, but only for positive inputs.

```
read n
g=$n
s=0
k=
if [ $n -gt 0 ] ; then echo "Not a positive number"
else
    while [ $n -gt 0 ]
       do
          k=$CC $n % 10 ))
          n=$CC $n / 10 ))
          s=$(C $s + $k ))
       done
echo "Sum of digit for given number is $s"
fi
```

Comment: Test cases passed only for positive numbers.

Comment: try pasting your code at https://shellcheck.net first. Fix those errors and if you still have trouble, then update your Q with corrected code. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the work

```
read a
s=0
if [[ $a -lt 0 ]]
then
    echo "Not a positive number"
else
    while [[ $a -gt 0 ]]
    do
        k=$(( $a % 10 ))
        a=$(( $a / 10 ))
        s=$(( $k + $s ))
    done
echo "Sum of digit for given number is $s"
fi
```

Comment: please add a brief description on how your code is solving the problem.